# My UICollectionView is not showing images

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The problem is that when I start my iOS app the collection view shows but any image is not shown. I have added a folder under Info.plist where my pictures are named 1.jpg and 2.jpg.

```
let array:[String] = ["1","2"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell 
    cell.imag.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to debug: `UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")` is nil? You should use `UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])` instead. Also, what is the frame of `cell.imag`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code should be like this

```
let array:[String] = ["1","2"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell 
  cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])

  return cell
}
```

Comment: My xcode has probably problem with collectionview class , everything works but collectionview doesn's start in simulator. I completetely don't know what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cell.imag.image = UIImage(named: "\(array[indexPath.row]).jpg")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn't work. I tried to set background to image view and everything is ok but is a problem with pictures;/ This doesn't show any pictures;/

Comment: have you try to access by using URL                                                                 let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("image", withExtension: "png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL!.path!)

Comment: Or move your image in "Assets.xcassets" and than try